# Telegram API - Password to Dots

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a ChatBot where using Python I interact with Telegram API to get update of previous message and reply suitably. My user's message could be a **password** which cannot be displayed and need to **converted into dots(*****)**. Is there such feature to convert PW to dots ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Telegram doesn't support this at this time, but you can try to use inline keyboard contain 0-9 number instead of it.